# issue with php shuffle multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle

hi there I declare an array variable and fill it:

```
foreach($urls as $url) 
{
    $webs[] = array( 'name' => $url['name'],
                     'url' => $url['link']);
}
```

it will fill something like this:

```
$webs: ((name:cnn,'link:cnn.com/1')
       (name:cnn,'link:cnn.com/1')
       (name:cnn,'link:cnn.com/1')
       (name:bbc,'link:bbc.com/1')
       (name:bbc,'link:bbc.com/1')
       (name:bbc,'link:bbc.com/1'))
```

Now I want to print it:

```
foreach($webs as $web) 
{
        echo "<br/>".$web['name'].':'.$web['url'];
}
```

result:

```
cnn: cnn.com/1
cnn: cnn.com/2
cnn: cnn.com/3
bbc: bbc.com/1
bbc: bbc.com/2
bbc: bbc.com/3
```

But I do not want it.
I want print all result but randomlay something like this:

```
bbc: bbc.com/1
cnn: cnn.com/1
bbc: bbc.com/3
cnn: cnn.com/3
cnn: cnn.com/2
cnn: cnn.com/3
bbc: bbc.com/2
```

I try

```
$webs = shuffle($webs);
foreach($webs as $web) 
    {
            echo "<br/>".$web['name'].':'.$web['url'];
    }
```

but no success with this error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

**Note**: In my real code, `$url['name']` is an another array.

Answer (score 0):

[`shuffle()`](http://php.net/shuffle) **TRUE** on success or **FALSE** on failure when you pass an array on it, you assigned `True` to `$webs` in this case. See more [shuffle](http://php.net/shuffle).

> **Note:** This function assigns new keys to the elements in array. It will remove any existing keys that may have been assigned, rather than
>   just reordering the keys.

```
shuffle($webs); //see here cause shuffle return true or false
foreach($webs as $web) 
    {
            echo "<br/>".$web['name'].':'.$web['url'];
    }
```